# Autodesk Forge - updating AggregatedView from jstree events

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

I'm having some difficulties understanding how to update the AggregatedView instance and adding models.

I have checkboxes in my jstree that - when checked - updates an array with selected node id's. But in order to add or remove these models from the viewer I am reloading the viewer. This clears the cache and incurs a lot of waiting time (models that were selected but not removed needs to be reloaded). Anyone have any suggestions how I can update the viewer withouth completelty resetting everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call a show/hide function of the aggregated viewer as I'm checking/unchecking models in the tree.